# Angular ionic single tap and double tap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, double

Hi I created a directive with the goal of intercepting single tap and double tap with HammerJs but it doesn't work the way I want it to and now I'm running out of ideas on how to solve the problem.

I tried this:

```
  @HostListener('tap', ['$event'])
   handleTaps(event) {
     if(event.tapCount == 2) {
      this.doubleTap.emit();
      event.prevenDefault();
     } else {
       this.singleTap.emit();
       event.prevenDefault();
    }
   }
```

The problem is that it does call Double Tap or double click but also the single tap before. What would be the solution to prevent this ? Use a set timeout ? Thanks

Comment: Blind guess, maybe put `event.prevenDefault()` first? Immediately after `handleTaps(event) {`

Comment: Thank you but it's not working, I don't have any idea

Answer (score 0):

**Basing on your code**,
try this

```
firstClicked = false;    
@HostListener('tap', ['$event'])
handleTaps(event) {
  if(!this.firstClicked){
       this.firstClicked = true;
       this.singleTap.emit();
       setTimeout(()=> {
          this.firstClicked = false;
       }, 200);
   }else{
       this.doubleTap.emit();
   }
}
```

here is an [**Angular example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdkgxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) that i made with it but with "click" event.
To be honest i'm not sure if setTimeout will work with IONIC, instead you can use native Timer API with the same previous concept i guess.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your solution. It's work with click but not tap. I found one solution even if it's not the cleanest one, I revised a bit the ex of the application with a custom event : DoubleTap with HammerJs and a press event where I reduced a bit the times

Comment: you are welcome @coco,  and  it worked with DoubleTap of HammerJs ? if yes than that's good i learn something new from you bro thank you a lot :))